# Android canvas drawRect() also redraws previous draws

Tags: java, android, canvas, drawrect

I've spent my whole day trying to figure out, how to draw squares with random colors, filling the whole screen. What i think happens is that, when drawRect() is called, it redraws previous draws, which doesnt make any sense, but its all i got. This is the code and i dont know what else to do, to fix this problem, here is the result.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItU3u.png

```
public class MyView extends View {
    public MyView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        int numberPerRow = 10;
        int x = getWidth()/numberPerRow;
        int y = getHeight();



        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
            for (int j = 0; i <= numberPerRow; j++){
                Paint paintTopRight = new Paint();
                int randColor = randomColor();
                paintTopRight.setColor(randColor);
                canvas.drawRect(j*x,i*x,x,x,paintTopRight);
            }
        }
    }


    public int randomColor() {

        int r = (int) (0xff * Math.random());
        int g = (int) (0xff * Math.random());
        int b = (int) (0xff * Math.random());

        return Color.rgb(r, g, b);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try using invalidate( ); at the end of your onDraw( ); function?

Comment: Yeah i've tried, but it starts flashing with different colors, but still not properly shown squares

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. It just puts your `View` in an endless draw loop. First, look at the parameters for the `drawRect()` method. The third and fourth parameters are `right` and `bottom`, not `width` and `height`. Second, check the inner `for` loop. You're using the outer loop's counter in the termination condition; i.e., `i <= numberPerRow`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop appears to have a typo; you use `i` when you should be using `j.

Change the new `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method to

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

    super.onDraw(canvas);
    int numberPerRow = 10;
    int x = getWidth()/numberPerRow;
    int y = getHeight();



    for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= numberPerRow; j++){
            Paint paintTopRight = new Paint();
            int randColor = randomColor();
            paintTopRight.setColor(randColor);
            canvas.drawRect(j*x,i*x,x,x,paintTopRight);
        }
    }
}
```